# doc() in apply-templates and the context item

Tags: xslt

I want to apply templates to a document loaded by `doc()` which works fine:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="doc('snippets.xml')//snippet" />
```

I want to select the `<snippet>` to be processed by using an attribute of the current context item:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="doc('snippets.xml')//snippet[@id=@snippet]" />
```

Which does not work, because obviously doc() changes the context item.
Is there a way to access the context from the surrounding template other than setting a variable like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="snippet_id" select="@snippet" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="doc('snippets.xml')//snippet[@id=$snippet_id]" />
```

Where can I find a specification how the context is influenced by doc()?

Comment: I have rolled back your question to what it was when I answered it. Your addition is a completely different question and should be asked separately.

Comment: you're right, will do that. thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `doc()` function, and everything to do with how a *predicate* is evaluated:
https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-predicates

XSLT has a special function to deal with exactly this problem:
https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#current-function

Here, you would use:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="doc('snippets.xml')//snippet[@id=current()/@snippet]" />
```